# Android HTC/Sony External Storage Permission Denied

Tags: java, android, storage, permission-denied

I do not understand what is going on here.

I get permission denied try trying to access External Storage on **HTC Wildfire S** although i set

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in the manifest file.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
```

return false.

```
File storage= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),FILENAME);
```

By calling `storage.createNewFile();` i get permission denied.

Stacktrace: `java.io.IOException: Permission denied`

**NOTE: The same application is working correctly on all Android Samsung devices. I have the problem only on HTC and Sony devices**

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please post your manifest and the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare  java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Comment: That is neither a manifest nor a stack trace. It is an error message.

Comment: @CommonsWare the same application is working correctly on all Android Samsung devices. I have the problem only on HTC and Sony devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the anwser by myself.

Quiet simple: i just use internal storage instead of
External one.

Answer (score 1):

Is your device plugged in your PC (USB) ? Did you check the status of your SDCard (how it is mounted, USB options while plugged in) ?

For this error : `java.io.IOException: Permission denied`
The destination file may aldready exist. Did you check that ?

Comment: String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) return false. The destination file doesn't exist

Comment: Did you check the syntax of your filename ?
Check if **storage.toString()** gives you a valid path for your file, or paste the result in the post.

Comment: Yes i do because the same application is working correctly on all Android Samsung devices. I have the problem only on HTC and Sony devices

Comment: Could you indicate the result of **Environment.getExternalStorageState();** in order to compare with several possible states that could cause the problem for this device (while plugged in or busy ..etc) ? ([documentation for different possible states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html))

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageState() returned removed

Comment: Is your device connected to your PC via USB ? If so, you could try different options for the connection or just test your app while not connected